# Problem Python: Yahoo finance timeout error

Tags: python, web-scraping, timeout, session-timeout, yahoo-finance

I've put together a web-**scraper**  that uses this [yahoo_finance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance/1.2.1) api. When I run the program to get daily data over the last 10 years, the following error:

> YQLQueryError: Query failed with error: "'Results may be truncated because the run exceeded the allowed max response timeout of 30000ms.'"

This error appears *sometimes* in the api's `Share.get_historical` method.

Can anyone offer some insight as to why this occurs and any possible remedies that I can explore?

Comment: Probably because your API calls are asking for too much data in one shot. Try breaking it down to smaller requests (maybe 1 year worth of data each time).

Answer (score 1):

Why does it happen?

Because the "run" exceeded 30 seconds which is a limit set by Yahoo. Presumably this is because you are requesting a lot of historical data. I don't think that it's a request timeout because I was able to get 16 years worth of historical data that took > 2 mins to complete. Probably something internal to Yahoo.

Possible remedies?

Try to make multiple queries with smaller date ranges, e.g. 6 months, and collate the results in your Python application.

Comment: Do you know why it only occurs sometimes though? I have timestamps before and after the get_historical() call that have shown successful pulls with time greater than 30s.

Comment: @RayFoo: Does it always fail for the same query? I don't know. I suppose it could be a load issue within Yahoo's severs. Perhaps sometimes it's too busy due to other users  to get all the data, and there is an internal timeout somewhere in their system. But that's just a guess. You will need to handle it in your application.